# HBITMAP StretchBlt caused image saturation

Tags: winapi, hbitmap, stretchblt

I used the following code to resize win32 HBITMAP.

```
HBITMAP ResizeBitmap(HDC hDC, HBITMAP source)
{
    HDC hMemDC2 = CreateCompatibleDC(hDC);
    HGDIOBJ hOld2 = SelectObject(hMemDC2, source);

    BITMAP bitmap = { 0 };
    GetObject(hBitmap, sizeof(BITMAP), &bitmap);

    float SCALE = IMAGE_SCALE;
    int nWidth = (int)ceil(bitmap.bmWidth / SCALE / 32) * 32;
    int nHeight = (int)ceil(bitmap.bmHeight / SCALE / 32) * 32;
    int dWidth = (int)round(bitmap.bmWidth / SCALE);
    int dHeight = (int)round(bitmap.bmHeight / SCALE);

    HDC hMemDC1 = CreateCompatibleDC(hDC);
    HBITMAP hBitmap1 = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hDC, nWidth, nHeight);
    HGDIOBJ hOld1 = SelectObject(hMemDC1, hBitmap1);

    StretchBlt(hMemDC1, 0, 0, dWidth, dHeight, hMemDC2, 0, 0, bitmap.bmWidth, bitmap.bmHeight, SRCCOPY);

    SelectObject(hMemDC1, hOld1);
    SelectObject(hMemDC2, hOld2);
    DeleteDC(hMemDC1);
    DeleteDC(hMemDC2);

    return hBitmap1;
}
```

However, I found the new image was saturated. As show bellow the original image
[image]

And the new image (Please ignore the green rectangle in the image)

[image]

Why?

Comment: What is `bmBitsPixel.bmBitsPixel` set to when `GetObject` returns?  Looks like you're getting downsampled from 24-bit color to 8-bit color

Comment: And for reference, what is `IMAGE_SCALE` set to?

Comment: Try using [SetStretchBltMode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-setstretchbltmode) to set the stretch mode to `HALFTONE`.

Comment: @JonathanPotter Beat me to it!

Comment: The current code is not enough to reproduce the issue, please provide more details, such as bmp parameters, and some undefined variables. By the way, I can successfully compile your code, but the issue does not appear, I used a 24-bit bmp to test.

Comment: bmBitsPixel is 32 for both bitmaps

Comment: IMAGE_SCALE=2.0f

Comment: When call SetStretchBitMode, apply it to which HDC? hDC, or hMemDC1, or hMemDC2 ?

Comment: @JonathanPotter is CORRECT!!!

Comment: `HALFTONE` is fairly expensive, and still only produces low quality results. If you want to resize an image properly, use the Windows Imaging Component instead.